# How to clone the row and make sure all date picker in each row is functioning?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, datepicker

I want to create a function using PHP, JavaScript & HTML where every time user click button "Add New Row", new row will be added in the table. It should be no limitation to add how many row. 1 more thing is each row have 1 input text with datepicker. What I should do to make sure all datepicker are functioning every time user add new row?

Here is the link to my sample code. http://jsbin.com/InUJASu/2/edit

Can someone help me to solve this problem? I've try so many way but I still didn't found a solution to solve it yet.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished best with Javascript.

Here's the revised [**code**](http://jsbin.com/InUJASu/5/edit)

---

You can use `datepicker[]` as your field name to push multiple values to `$_POST['datepicker']`.

For example, a form posted like this:

```
<form action="post_dates.php" method="post">
    <input name="datepicker[]" value="9/9/2012">
    <input name="datepicker[]" value="4/17/2012">
</form>
```

Would set the `$_POST['datepicker']` as an array with the values `array('9/9/2012', '4/17/2012')` which you could iterate over to support any amount of dates.